# Insert UITextField above a table view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a regular TableViewController and want to add a UITextField above that will populate the TableView data. How I can programmatically place right above the cells?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about a UISearchBar? Do you want the user to add to the uitextfield and then generate the data based on the provided text?

Comment: Yes but with a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the UITextField in the UITableViewController's header.

Use the UITableViewController Delegate methods to set the properties of the header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Alternatively, you could use a UISearchBar.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];
searchBar.delegate = self; 
[searchBar sizeToFit];  
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Then, in the UISearchBar delegate methods.

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBar Delegate Methods

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // Remove the keyboard
    [searchBar endEditing:YES];

    // This method filters the data based on the search text.
    [self filterDataUsingSearchText:searchBar.text];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // Remove the keyboard
    [searchBar endEditing:YES];

    // Clear the text on cancel
    searchBar.text = @"";
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // This method filters the data based on the search text.
    [self filterDataUsingSearchText:searchText];
}

#pragma mark -
```

Documentation:

[UISearchBar Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html)

[Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)